# How can I define the background color and font size for an accordion in Bootstrap 4 Vuejs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-4

Hi I have an accordion with Bootstrap 4 and Vuejs like this:

```
<div class="faq_accordion" role="tablist">
    <b-card no-body class="mb-1">
      <b-card-header header-tag="header" class="p-1" role="tab">
        <b-button block v-b-toggle.accordion-1 variant="secondary">¿Cómo se seleccionó los beneficiarios?</b-button>
      </b-card-header>
      <b-collapse id="accordion-1" accordion="my-accordion" role="tabpanel">
        <b-card-body>
          <b-card-text>I start opened because <code>visible</code> is <code>true</code></b-card-text>
          <b-card-text>{{ text }}</b-card-text>
        </b-card-body>
      </b-collapse>
    </b-card>
</div>
```

I added this to the css:

```
.faq_accordion .card-header {
  background-color: #f1f1f180 !important;
  background: transparent;
}
```

But it does not work the background does not take that color, how can I fix it? and how can I add the font size to the fonts? Thanks!

Comment: You're selecting a card-header class that is a descendant of a faq_accordion class, but I see no card-header class in your code. You probably meant to select the `p-1` class.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in `Vue` you need to do it in the hard way with deep properties, change it in your `CSS`:

In Vue 2 (Boostrap Vue is based on this):

```css
    ::v-deep .faq_accordion .card-header {
      background-color: #f1f1f180 !important;
      background: transparent;
    }
```

In Vue 3:

```css
    :deep(.faq_accordion .card-header) {
      background-color: #f1f1f180 !important;
      background: transparent;
    }
```

I hope it works for you.